# How to exclude a line break from regex character class?

Tags: regex, pcre

Given this PCRE pattern:

```
/(<name>[^<>]*<\/name>[^<>]*<phone>[^<>]*<\/phone>)/
```

And this subject text:

```
<name>John Stevens</name>  <phone>888-555-1212</phone>
<name>Peter Wilson</name>  
<phone>888-555-2424</phone>
```

How can I get the Regular Expression to match the first name-phone pair but not the second?  I don't want to match pairs that are separated by line breaks.  I tried including an end-of-line in the negated character class like so `[^<>$]*` but nothing changed.

You can use the following online tools to test your expressions:
http://rubular.com/
http://www.regextester.com/
Thank you.

Comment: Inside a character class, the `$`  loses its special meaning and becomes simply a literal dollar sign. What you want is: `[^<>\r\n]` as sawa suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will do it

```
/<name>[^<>]*<\/name>[^<>\r\n]*<phone>[^<>]*<\/phone>/
```

Whatever you put in the class `[  ]` must be something that represents a single character. `$` is interpreted as literal `$` within a class, probably because `$` as line end is 0-width, and could not be interpreted as such within a class. (Edited after comment by ridgerunner)

By the way, I took off the parentheses that surrounds your regex because whatever matches it can be referred to as the whole match.

Comment: +1 (but the `$` does have an effect inside a char class - it matches a dollar sign.)

Comment: @ridgerunner Thanks for pointing out. I will correct my answer.

Comment: I also added `\r` as pointed out by ridgerunner. I only had unix in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to match pairs separated by line breaks then following regex will do the job:

```
/(<name>[^<>]*<\/name>.*?<phone>[^<>]*<\/phone>)/
```

Matches only first name, phone pair since dot `.` will not match `EOL` but `[^<>]` will match it.

Tested it on http://rubular.com/r/amXvq20sl8

Comment: Thank you.  But I also needed to exclude `<>` to prevent capturing other tags.

Comment: It wouldn't really hurt to make it `[^<>]*` above, however I think once we are already inside `<name>` then to capture everything up to `</name>' we just need `[<]*`

Comment: Right, and I like that change.  What I omitted from the subject text is that there could be other tags between name and phone that I don't want to capture if they're there. ie `<name>Mark</name><name>Bill</name><phone>888...</phone>`.  The `.*` would capture both names on that same line. I know I could make it lazy instead of greedy, but that could negatively affect other parts of my pattern. I think the `\r\n` as stated above will work for me. With the addition of your change: `[^<\r\n]`.

Answer (score 0):

Those sites don't seem to support the whole PCRE syntax.  I used this site:
http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php

And this worked:

```
/^(<name>[^<>]*<\/name>[^<>$]*<phone>[^<>]*<\/phone>)/

/(?-s)(<name>[^<>]*<\/name>.*<phone>[^<>]*<\/phone>)/
```

is probably better