# using (?s) Regex options in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-code

I am used to writing regular expressions that support multiple options to specify case sensitivity, white space ignoring, meaning of `.` etc... In C#, these options are specified with `(?i)`, `(?x)` and `(?s)` respectively.

How can these modifiers be used with Visual Studio Code find functionality? I am getting an error

> Invalid regular expression: Invalid group.

**Example**:

```regex
q.*?abc.*?q
```

will match `<q>heheabchihi</q>`, but not

```xml
<q>hehe
  abchihi</q>
```

due to the `.` not matching all characters (`\n` is omitted). Adding `(?s)` fixes that in C# regex, but not in Visual Studio Code. What is the Visual Studio Code way of using regex options?

Comment: Show us the regex that you are having problem with

Comment: Can you give a [mcve]?

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: I don't use VSCode much but ["VS Code now supports multiline search! Same as in the editor, a regex search executes in multiline mode _only if it contains a \n literal_"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53270908/8967612).

Answer (score 4):

**Updated answer**

in my original answer, I have overseen the visual studio code requirement, and here I update my answer based on that.

I have made this regex to find the match in Visual Studio Code.

```
q.*?(.|\n)+?.q
```

This will find the following:

[image]

Tested also here https://regex101.com/r/f3vKcU/1

Inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66000581/3088349).

Hope that helps.

---

**Original answer**

You can do something simple as adding `[^<>]` in your regex.

So change this

```
q.*?abc.*?q
```

to

```
q.[^<>]*?abc.*?q
```

Will do the job.

Check it https://regex101.com/r/DWQ9ZP/1

I got the inspiration from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768533/how-to-exclude-a-line-break-from-regex-character-class).

Answer (score 1):

you could match any character or newline like this:

```regex
<q>[\s\S\n]*<\/q>
```

this would select everything inside the q tag until it is closed

i used `[\s\S]` to select every other character aside `\n`, it would translate to *every whitespace-character and every non-whitespace-character*

---

added note: since `*` is a quantifier for 0 or more, the `?` becomes unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

to match new line you can combine regex options `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Singleline`

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"q.*?abc.*?q";
        string input = @"<q>hehe
  abchihi</q>";
        Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern,  RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        Console.WriteLine(m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code [doesn't support `.` matching newline](https://docs.rs/regex/1.5.5/regex/#matching-one-character).

You can use `(.|\n)*?`, `[\w\W]*?` instead of `.*?` to match multiline characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
(<\w+>[\w\s]*<\/\w+>)
```

For normal languages above finds every `<tag>text</tag>` doesn't matter how many lines they take

However, if the aim is to use the regex to perform a regex search within VS Code then use below

```
(<\w+>[\w\s]*\n?<\/\w+>)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to search for something and create a group for it you should use `()`
For example, this regex searches for `s` character and captures it into a group :

```
(s)
```

or this example searches for `myExample` strings and captures it into a group:

```
(myExample)
```

So you can use the group value in replace textbox, in your case, please search for `(i)` and replace it with `x$1` to understand how it works. (group starts from $1)

for Non-capturing group you should use `(?:)` , it means that you create a group but you don't want to capture it.
in your case search for `(i)` and replace it with `x$1` you will see nothing will be captured.

**And when you try to use `(?s)` it tries to create a Non-capturing group and you will get an `Invalid group` error** because you missed a `:` character.

For your search you can use `q[\s\S\r\n]*abc[\s\S\r\n]*.q`

This is a more advanced example for replacing first character with the last character of something :
Search for `(\w)(\w+)(\w)` and replace this with `$3$2$1`